# History of Half-Life Science

Tags: half-life-series, portal-series

Are there any stories that go deeper into these the histories and purposes of locations like Black Mesa and Aperture?

Comment: Pre-emptive: Please don't use [this site](http://members.shaw.ca/halflifestory/) as a reference without using other sources to back it up. That site makes big assumptions based on things not found in any of the games.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Combine Overwiki has full articles on [Aperture Science](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Aperture_Science) and [Black Mesa](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Mesa). These articles cover all that is canonically known about these organizations. A quick summary:

#### Aperture Science

- Location: [Upper Michigan](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/File:Underground_trophycase_newspaper.png)
- Purpose: Originally created as a shower curtain manufacturer by a successful shower curtain salesman, the company eventually evolved "into an experimental physics research institution and a bitter rival of Black Mesa" after the owner became deathly ill and brain-damaged.

#### Black Mesa

- Location: [A city called "Black Mesa" in New Mexico](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/File:Gordon_letter_PS2.jpg)
- Purpose: Helmed by the U.S. Government, Black Mesa conducts research in various theoretical and applied science fields.

Comment: Hunh. GF taught in Austria?

Answer (score 7):

Valve had a "GLaDOS Terminal" set up at www.aperturescience.com for a long time. With the right logon and commands you could see a compressed history of Aperture Science. It appears to be gone now (replaced by a Christmas video) but you can still access it [here](http://replay.web.archive.org/20100408211755/http://www.aperturescience.com/). Type `login`, Use the username `cjohnson` and the password `tier3` to log in, then issue the `notes` command.

Comment: For those who are curious, the username and password are found in one of the Rat Man's dens in Portal.